# Passportjs extract user from isAuthenticated function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Alrigh, so I have set up an entire passport local authorization, every thing works pretty perfectly, except I can't seem to wrap my head around one issue with passport.js.

I am authorizing users through sessions (they work fine), however I can't seem to extract the user info from that session, although if I manually check my session db, for every session there is a userid (which links to the user).
Also the deserialize functions seem to return the user and the log is showing the correct user.

Now the problem is that I can't seem to pass this user<->session info anywhere in my routes.
The issue that I seem to have with this is that people that are logged in, are authorized, but they can fiddle with the request body as much as they like, doing things as posting messages in their name, logging them out, ...

Code example:

```
router.post('/games/:id/verify', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        log('@POST verify for game with id: ' + req.params.id);
        gameController.postVerify(req.params.id, req, res);
    });
```

In this code, it just checks if a user is logged in, if possible, I want to check *which* user is logged in to that session, so that he cannot verify this game if he was not part of it.

Let's say user A, B were part of the game and need to verify it. This function allows user C who is logged in to verify for them, because this function only checks if the user is logged in.

If I can pass the logged in user (user C in the test case) to the gameController, I can write my own checks in there and throw them out.

Answer (score 1):

Passport will populate `req.user` when authentication has succeeded. It will be populated by the data provided by `deserializeUser`, which generally is a database record of the user.

You can use that information to limit other database queries/checks/etc to make sure that the logged-in user is allowed to access particular information.